# Join on Identity and Another Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am trying to figure out how do I create a join statement on Identity and another table that I have, in this case TeamMember.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var j =
    Db.TeamMembers.Join(MemberManager.Users,
    c => c.MemberId,
    cm => cm.Id,
    (c, cm) => new {TeamMember = c, Member = cm})
    .Where(m => m.TeamMember.TeamId == team.Id && !m.TeamMember.MemberId.Equals(team.CaptainId));

List<TeamMember> teamMembers = new List<TeamMember>();
foreach (var result in j)
{
    var teamMember = new TeamMember
    {
        GameDisplayName = result.Member.Alias
    };
    teamMembers.Add(teamMember);
}
```

And the error that I have is

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that `MemberManager` and `Db` are different objects. It would have to query one and pass the results to the other in order to make this function (imagine if they pointed to different databases), and it's not willing to do that by default, because it'd be a bad idea more often than not.

The simple option is just to change `MemberManager.Users` to `Db.Users`. If I understand your setup correctly, that should fix it.

That said, I don't understand why `MemberManager` exists at all, so maybe I don't understand it. In that case, you'd have to do something like this:

```
var team = /*...*/;

var teamMembers = Db.TeamMembers
    .Where(c => c.TeamId == team.Id && c.MemberId != team.CaptainId)
    .ToList();

var teamMemberIds = teamMembers.Select(c => c.MemberId);

var members = MemberManager.Users
    .Where(c => teamMemberIds.Any(x => c.Id == x))
    .ToList();

var j = teamMembers
    .Join(members, c => c.MemberId, cm => cm.Id, (c, cm) => new
        {
            TeamMember = c,
            Member = cm
        });
```

It'd be best to avoid this if you can, since it is two separate server calls. But it does let you use multiple contexts.